# Converting an ELF binary into an .o file

Tags: c, executable, elf, object-files, objcopy

The question is as stated in the title: Is it possible to convert an ELF binary file `hello_world` into an object file `hello_world.o`, which can be used to generate a new binary `hello_world_2` which is a replica of `hello_world`?

So from my searching, it seems that this is a bit difficult. I have found one method that is the closest which is:

Using either `objcopy` or `ld` to create an object file from the binary. An example command of this would be:

`ld -r -b binary ./hello_world -o hello_world.o`

This command creates an object file consisting of sections something like

```
00000000 l    d  .data    00000000 .data
00000000 g       .data    00000000 _binary_hello_world_start
00000010 g       .data    00000000 _binary_hello_world_end
00000010 g       *ABS*    00000000 _binary_hello_world_size
```

That can be accessed if you link this newly generated object file with a separate C file (https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/linking-a-binary-blob-with-gcc/). However, this is a bit different than what I wish to do since I need to create a separate code just to access this new object file.

This: [Make Executable Binary File From Elf Using GNU objcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944441/make-executable-binary-file-from-elf-using-gnu-objcopy) StackOverflow discussion provides a great explanation of a similar topic. However, I'm still wondering if there was some sort of way to achieve my original question of:

`binary` --> `binary.o` --> `binary_new`

Side note: If anyone is curious why I am trying to do this, is because I am trying to **add a .rodata section** into the binary that I have no source code for (this is a whole another problem which is extensively discussed below). This procedure is recommended to do with an object file because newly added section into the binary will be readable in the load-time.

1. [How can the --add-section switch of OBJCOPY be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823416/how-can-the-add-section-switch-of-objcopy-be-used)
2. [How to replace a section of an elf file with another using objcopy or libelf, such that it does get loaded into the Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647589/how-to-replace-a-section-of-an-elf-file-with-another-using-objcopy-or-libelf-su)
3. [Define new code section in assembly code to compile ELF binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440283/define-new-code-section-in-assembly-code-to-compile-elf-binary)

Thank you for any suggestions in advance,

Comment: I'm curious, I've seen MANY use cases of patching an executable in my years, that didn't involve having the source. Why can't you just splice it into the EXE and update any offsets like a virus or a crack does?

Comment: Might be possible if the code was compiled with `-g` for debugging info or similar.  Otherwise, an optimized binary isn't going to know it's own function names like a `.o` file would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems that this is a bit difficult

That's a bit of understatement: for all *practical* purposes this is *impossible* to do (at least on ELF platforms), because in the process of linking `hello_world` the linker *discards* much of the information that was contained on object files which comprise `hello_world`, and is necessary to reconstruct it again.

> I am trying to add a .rodata section into the binary that I have no source code for

That is unlikely to be your *real* goal -- the original binary will not use your added `.rodata`, so your goal *must be* something *else*. See also http://xyproblem.info/.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I agree with you on all of the statements, and I see that this is downright impossible to do. Just to answer your second point, the ultimate goal is to be able to read the .rodata section of the original binary with the patched binary (using binary instrumentation such as Intel PIN). I have already achieved this for the binaries that I have ```.o``` files for, hence I was wondering if it was possible to do it for the binary without source code. Sincerely.